# pyInstaller: ImportError: No module named 'praw'

Tags: python, pyinstaller, praw

I wanted to pack my script using pyInstaller. I run `pyinstaller file.py -F`, file is created successfully, but when running I get `ImportError: No module named 'praw'`. So I created new file containing only `import praw` and run `pyinstaller file.py -F --hidden-import=praw` but still get the same error when running.
I was unable to find anything similar, most issues were solved by using `--hidden-import`.
Any ideas on how it can be solved?
EDIT:
`praw` is installed inside virtual environment and running the script directly works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem pyinstaller run outside the virtualenv.
Try switch to your virtualenv and run:

```
python -m PyInstaller -F file.py
```

Comment: Thank you. That was the issue. `pyinstaller file.py` worked fine on previous projects.

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend to look at pyenv or virtualenv. Activate these env's and install the `praw module` here. This should work.

Comment: I have praw installed inside virtual environment

Comment: Where did you define your virtualenv? Inside the project folder or outside?

Comment: Inside project folder.

Comment: try to define the env outside the projectfolder and try again. Post the full traceback in the comments

Comment: Nothing changed. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'praw'
Failed to execute script file`

Answer (score 0):

This command might help you out. It installs the Praw module for you. Make sure you have pip installed!

```
pip install praw
```

Comment: OK, what operating system are you using?

Comment: Linux Mint 18.1 but also had issues on Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve the issue:

When using Python2.7, or starting the shell like `python2`, we need to do

```
python2 -m pip install --user praw
```

to make sure they are linked during installation.

Same idea for `python3` shell.